# bcrypt compare against a Laravel hashed password

Tags: javascript, laravel, hash, bcrypt

I'm trying to create a react-native mobile app for my company, we currently have a website that a developer built with Laravel. I wan't my mobile app to use the same table that the Laravel based website uses for authentication, are there any JS libraries that I can use to compare plaintext passwords against Laravel hashes? `bcrypt.compare` doesn't seem to work, I'm assuming that's due to different hashing algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Hash::check('plain-text', 'hashed password')`

Answer (score 0):

Hash::check("plain text here ", "hashed password")
and make sure plain text has more than hashed value